# how to hide & show rows of a html table in xmlt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to figure out how to hide the rows in my xslt style sheet. I have created a XSLT style sheet that shows every row avalible... but I would like to have it so when the xml is loaded some of the rows are hidden.

This is what the xslt (xml style sheet) looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/Catalogue">
     <html>
     <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Tales">
        <xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
            <table border="0" width="550">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%"><b><xsl:value-of select="Tale"/></b></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
                    <xsl:text>  -  </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Type"/></td>
                 </tr>
                <tr>
                <xsl:if test="Prereq != ''">
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><xsl:value-of select="Prereq"/></td>
                </xsl:if>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <xsl:if test="Action != ''">
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0"><xsl:value-of select="Action"/></td>
                </xsl:if>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <xsl:if test="Description != ''">
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EBEBEB"><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
                </xsl:if>
                </tr>
            </table>
               <br/>  <br/>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to know how to make the rows of the table that hold Prereq, Action and description hidden when the page opens but then by pressing a button or a + link to show those rows.. then if clicked again hidden.

I have seen some tutorials that show is being done in javascript but as soon as I try to add this code the xml data is not displayed anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: this is what the xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="bloodandguts.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<Catalogue>
<Tales>
<Talent>Training</Talent>
<Cost>1</Cost>
<Type>Any</Type>
<Prereq></Prereq>
<Action>Passive</Action>
<Description>Confers proficiency of a single type of training</Description>
</Tales>
// then lots more <Tales></Tales>
</Catalogue>
```

UPDATE:

This is how I am adding  into my xslt... but for some reason its stopping my xml file from showing anything

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <xsl:template match="/Catalogue">
     <html>
     <body>
```

Comment: Please provide an input xml example. And yes you need to have some javascript (perhaps jQuery) to have dynamic behavior in html.

Comment: I have updated with xml example.. showing one of the <Talents> there are many more.. but decided to onl show the one.

Comment: Also your table looks somehow strange, the first row has two columns the other have only one or non.

Comment: colspan = 2 means its merging the two colums into one.

Comment: Ok yes I overlooked that. But still if  e.g Description  is empty there is no column at all.

Comment: there will be no row.. but still there will be colums.. i think.

Comment: You should put the `<xsl:if test="Description != ''">` around the `<tr>`

Comment: good point!!! thanks for that totally didnt see it.. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only to give you some hits to continue, or to clarify your question.

It should be no problem to add some javascript to your example. For example I use jQuery even if it is not necessary for such an easy example.

- Add javascript library in html `<header>`if necessary:

  ```
         <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
  ```
- Add an id or class to your row you like to hide and show later.

  ```
  <tr id="test1" style="display:none">
  ```
- Add an onclick handler to your header row.

  ```
  <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">
      <div onclick="$('#test1').show()">+</div>
      <b>
          <xsl:value-of select="Tale"/>
      </b>
  </td>
  ```

Be aware this only shows how javascript (jquery) can be added to your example. This will only show a hidden row and will only work with one  `<Tales>` entry, because id's in html should be unique. Therefore you can either creat unique id's from xslt or add a class to your dynamic row and search for them from your javascript handler.

Update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Catalogue">
        <html>
            <header>
            <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
            </header>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="Tales">
                    <xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
                        <table border="0" width="550">
                            <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">
            <div onclick="$('#test1').show()">+</div>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="Tale"/>
            </b>
        </td>
                                <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
                                    <xsl:text>  -  </xsl:text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr >
                                <xsl:if test="Prereq != ''">
                                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Prereq"/>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="test1" style="display:none">
                                <xsl:if test="Action != ''">
                                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Action"/>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:if test="Description != ''">
                                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A weird thing happens, as soon as I enter your first line of code if i reload my xml page nothing shows.. when i delete it everything shows again.. this is the trouble i have been having with other code other than xslt

Comment: Hm what browser do you use? This works with e.g. Chrome. Do you have jquery.js in the same directory as your xml? Should this run on a server or local in filesystem?

Comment: I am looking at it using chrome on my local drive, I have had to run **/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files switch** to get it to work originally. I have not added jquery.js into my file.. do I need to do that?

Comment: I just added jquery.js into my folder.. and still nothing is howing.. Check up updated question to see how I am adding that first line of code.

Comment: The above code is based on jQuery. `$(..)' is an jQuery call. But it should be possible also without jquery.

Comment: The script should in the generate html header. `<xsl:template match="/Catalogue">
  <html>
   <header>
   <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
   </header>
   <body>`

Comment: yup putting that code into header worked fine.. the only thing now is to get the + to work.. I think the problem is is that i am not hiding the rows initally?

Comment: whoops totaly missed the tr id etc.. so added that and it worked like  you said it would.. so now I just need to figure out a way to get them all working individually. :)

Comment: is ther a way to click it again and have it dissipear?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at jquery documentation for a while. For example [`$('.target').toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Where .target is class name. If you cant find a way pelsase create a new qustion.

Comment: okay thanks.. I have ust been reading up on this a minutes ago and going to try now... its just hard because there are alot of incompatibilities with xslt html jquery etc.. so will keep trying.